# How to access values inside an object?

Tags: php, json

```
{
   "http://url.com": {
      "id": "http://url.com",
      "shares": 11111
   }
}
```

I need to access 'id' and 'shares' and seems like the normal

```
($results->shares)
```

doesn't work here, any suggestions? thanks.

**EDIT with full code:**

```
<?php 

include __DIR__ . '/config.php';

function do_curl($start_index, $stop_index) {

    // Do query here to get all pages with ids between start index and stop index

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mmakers WHERE id >= $start_index and id <= $stop_index";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $fanpages_query[] = 'https://graph.facebook.com/?ids='.$row['domain'];
    }
    return $fanpages_query;

}


$fanpages = do_curl($_GET['start_index'], $_GET['stop_index']);
$fanpages_count = count($fanpages);


$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();

for($i = 0; $i < $fanpages_count; $i++)
{
    $url = $fanpages[$i];
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
}
do {
    curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
} while($running > 0);


for($i = 0; $i < $fanpages_count; $i++)
{
    $results = json_decode(curl_multi_getcontent($curl_arr[$i]));

    $sql_mm = "SELECT * FROM mmakers WHERE domain='".($results->id)."'";
    $result_mm = mysql_query($sql_mm) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_mm = mysql_fetch_array($result_mm);

    if ($row_mm['type'] == 'auto') {
    $sql_d = "SELECT domain FROM domains_list WHERE used='no' AND directory='".$row_mm['directory']."' AND type='auto' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
    $result_d = mysql_query($sql_d) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_d = mysql_fetch_array($result_d);
    } else {
    $sql_d = "SELECT domain FROM domains_list WHERE used='no' AND directory='".$row_mm['directory']."' AND type='jaa' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
    $result_d = mysql_query($sql_d) or die(mysql_error());
    $row_d = mysql_fetch_array($result_d);
    }

    mysql_query("UPDATE mmakers SET shares = '".($results->shares)."' WHERE id='".$row_mm['id']."'") or die(mysql_error());

}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to decode the JSON as an array:

```
$results = json_decode($json, true);
```

Then assuming you don't know the URL, you have to loop over the array:

```
foreach($results as $url => $data) {
    echo $url, ' shares: ', $data['shares'];
}
```

If you know the URL, you can do

```
$results['http://url.com']['shares'];
```

Comment: Sorry didn't noticed the part where you said "assuming you don't know the URL". anyway i included a full code some basic example will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$results->{"http://url.com"}->shares
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot one property.

```
echo $results->{"http://url.com"}->shares;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this...

```
$results = json_decode($json, true);
echo $results[0]["shares"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = '{
   "http://url.com": {
      "id": "http://url.com",
      "shares": 11111
   }
}';

$object = json_decode($content);
$object->{'http://url.com'}->shares; //11111
```

- http://codepad.org/WkpwLCvp

Answer (score 0):

When decoding JSON, set `$assoc` (second argument of [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/json_decode)) to `true`:

```
$jsonData = json_decode($jsonText, true);
$url = 'http://url.com';
var_dump($jsonData[$url]['id']);
var_dump($jsonData[$url]['shares']);
```